# Is it possible to run a virtualized instance of windows on a server with native ZFS?

Tags: linux, virtualization, nas, freebsd, zfs

I am intersted in setting up a home server / render pc. My goal is to have 8 or more HDDs for storage and redundancy and to use the available processing power of the server to render videos in Adobe Premiere in a windows environment with the aid of a GPU. I know that unRAID can give this basic functionality, but I would prefer to use ZFS as it provides better performance and redundancy.

Is it possible to use a linux or freeBSD based hypervisor that maintains the ZFS drive pool that also allows windows to run with PCI-e passthrough for the GPU? Or would such a system be too inefficient?

Working specs for the server are 2x E5-2670's and 96 GB of DDR3 RAM.

Comment: Very much related: [What are the performance implications of running VMs on a ZFS host?](https://serverfault.com/q/532272/58408) on [sf].

Answer (score 0):

It's not just a question of being inefficient (though that's the case as well.)

While you can use ZFS inside a virtual machine, ZFS really should be run stand alone.  If your virtual disks are running on top of a legacy filesystem then the primary advantage of using ZFS, automatic repair of damaged data, is gone. The ZFS pool is inside the virtual disk, and can repair damage to data stored on that pool inside that virtual disk, but if the virtual disk itself (which is stored on the host system's traditional filesystem) is damaged, then there is nothing that could be done about it.  Using it in a virtualized environment would most likely cause problems with ZFS doing some of its automated tasks, as well as add some resource limitations on it.

It'd be best to simply attach a simple / low-end cpu, to a decent hw raid card, and dedicate it as a ZFS NAS box.

Comment: The point was to run VMs on top of ZFS, not ZFS in VMs.

Comment: Your advice may incur additional costs, as for throughput, you would need 10GBit ethernet. If not already on the board, this is quite expensive. In contrast, on the hypervisor side you usually get free virtual 10Gbit ethernet, which can be tuned to deliver nearly double the bandwidth, see for example http://blog.cyberexplorer.me/2013/03/improving-vm-to-vm-network-throughput.html

Comment: No need to run ZFS on top of hardware RAID. In fact, it's very often strongly recommended against, because it adds complexity for no good reason: ZFS with a good JBOD HBA can do everything a good RAID HBA can do, and more. Rather, common advice is to give ZFS each individual disk, and set up redundancy at the ZFS volume managent level. Doing so has the additional benefit that you are essentially independent of the hardware; you can take those disks, hook them up to some other controller, and it Just Works (tm) (at least as long as ZFS support is available).

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use a linux or freeBSD based hypervisor that maintains the ZFS drive pool that also allows windows to run with PCI-e passthrough for the GPU? Or would such a system be too inefficient?

Yes, it is possible as long as you have vt-d (your CPUs do).

You basically can do one of the following:

1. Storage controller is virtualized:

   - Install any hypervisor (ESXi, KVM, HyperV) of your choice on bare metal (take note that some have limitations, for example ESXi does not passthrough consumer video cards from Nvidia, only from AMD)
   - Create a small storage VM with a OS of your choice that supports ZFS (Solaris, illumos derivates, FreeBSD, Linux), assign your HBA to this machine and configure your disks as you would on bare metal inside the storage VM
   - Share your storage in the internal network on the hypervisor (NFS or iSCSI) and create a new VM storage pool on it
   - Create your Windows VM and any other VMs on this new VM storage pool, assign your GPU to your Windows VM, install as usual
2. Storage controller and hypervisor are on the same machine:

   - Setup your system of choice on bare metal, it must support both ZFS and virtualisation with GPU passthrough (this pretty much limits it to KVM on Linux currently)

The first solution is more flexible in the choice of hypervisor and OSes (choose the best OS for each task, no need to mix tasks on VMs) but is more complicated to setup (because of the additional storage network layer needed) and to manage (because you cannot log in directly to the hypervisor). In theory the second point would be true for the second solution also, but I think you can hack KVM so that you can use the hypervisor (dom0) itself (although with security downsides).